# How redraw UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

In loadDidLoad controller call method with thread, like that:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(loadImages) object:nil];
    [self.operationQueue addOperation:operation];
    [operation release]; 
}
```

loadImages method downloading image and show it:

```
- (void) loadImages {

    @synchronized (self) {
        // download image...
        // ...
        // and next:
        UIImageView *imageView = [imageViews objectAtIndex:currentImageIndex];
        [imageView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setNeedsDisplay) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
        [imageView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImage:) withObject:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData] waitUntilDone:YES];
    }
         //...
}
```

that work if show view first time, next time i must rotate iphone to show images.
why view doesn't redraw?

---

i tried this code according to advices:

```
// imageButton is a UIView with button, image and label
NSData   *imageData = [[HttpClient sharedInstance] getResourceWithCache:thumbPath];
[imageButton performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImage:) withObject:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData] waitUntilDone:YES];
[imageButton performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setNeedsDisplay) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
[imageButton drawRect:imageButton.frame];
```

but do not work.

Comment: What happens if you first set the image and then do setNeedsDisplay?

Comment: What else are you synchronizing? This is *very* dangerous, especially with long operations like downloading. Use the debugger - attach a breakpoint and enable it on second or third run and check the *whole* loadImages code.

Comment: right now i can't check what happend if i change the order of call selectors, i think it doesn't work, but i will try it. i would be grateful if someone would show me example code how redraw view and subviews from thread after set images into views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your problem is in the line

```
        [imageView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setNeedsDisplay) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

You would need to call setNeedsDisplay in self.view and not on self, as thats a method for UIView and not UIViewController.

Double check this by subclassing your view and putting a break point in drawRect: , as setNeedsDisplay must call drawRect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that `loadDidLoad` is a typo, and that you meant `viewDidLoad`.

The `viewDidLoad` method is called when the view controller is done loading. It only does this once, unless the app receives a memory warning and the view controller gets unloaded.

If you're retaining the view controller and later showing the same view controller object again, the `viewDidLoad` method does not get called again.

If you need to perform an action every time the view controller gets pushed onto the view stack, you can use `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:`.

Comment: viewDidLoad and thread run, but view doesn't redraw until i rotate iphone. i tried call loadImages from viewWillAppear, according to advice, but same behaviour, view are redraw after long time or after rotate iphone

Comment: Are you sure it just doesn't take a long time to download the images?

Comment: if call shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: progamically after downloading look fine, but that aren't correct solution